# Why does "break;" not allow me to exit my loop like it should?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript and am creating a rudimentary hangman game. However, I keep getting an error when trying to break out of my loop. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var words = [
  "javascript",
  "monkey",
  "amazing",
  "pancake"
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  answerArray[i] = "_";
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;

while (remainingLetters > 0) {
  alert(answerArray.join(" "));
}

var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing.");

if (guess === null) {
  break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
  alert("Please enter a single letter.");
} else {
  for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    if (word[j] === guess) {
      answerArray[j] = guess;
      remainingLetters--;
    }
  }
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
```

Comment: Which loop is the break expected to interrupt ?

Comment: Wont that `while` just go forever?

Comment: "_I keep getting an error_" Why would you not tell us what the error is?

Comment: Can you please properly indent your code? It's currently unreadable.

Comment: `while (remainingLetters > 0) {
            alert(answerArray.join(" "));
        }` Javascript can never stop doing that, and while it is doing that, will not do anything else. Your only chance is to modify `remainingLetters` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @connexo. I had a closing bracket after the alert, when it should have been at the very end. Thank you to everyone for helping.

Could you point me in the direction of indenting properly? I'm extremely new and trying to do my best and follow the rules.

Comment: Curious, why are people downvoting this question? It's an honest question, and I couldn't find the answer after searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the break inside the loop

```js
var words = [
            "javascript",
            "monkey",
            "amazing",
            "pancake"
        ];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            answerArray[i] = "_";
        }
var remainingLetters = word.length;
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
            alert(answerArray.join(" "));
            var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing.");
if (guess === null) {
    break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Please enter a single letter.");
} else {
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
        if (word[j] === guess) {
            answerArray[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
        }
    }
}
        }

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code to understand the scope I would assume that you are using break incorrectly. Instead you should be using return.

Break is used inside loops (for, while, for in, switch etc).
Where as return is used to return from functions, if blocks and can either return a value or not.

```html
if (guess === null) {
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Break in javascript is only for loops, not if statements so you will get that error message when running your code. Secondly, the while loop becomes an infinite loop as you are not able to stop the alerts to enter anything into the prompt
I would rewrite it like this:

```
var words = [
        "javascript",
        "monkey",
        "amazing",
        "pancake"
    ];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        answerArray[i] = "_";
    }

var remainingLetters = word.length;
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
        alert(answerArray.join(" "));
        var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing.");
        if(!guess){
          alert('Please enter a letter!')
        }
        else if(guess.length != 1) {
          alert('Please enter a single letter!')
        }
        else {
            for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess) {
               answerArray[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
              } 
            }
        }
    }

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd misplaced a closing bracket. Typical rookie mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the if(!break) is the same thing as if(break == null) read about Truthy and [Falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in javascript

Comment: No problem we are all here to get better my dude!